# How to update database programmatically from mvcArea

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm using **EF6 Code First Migrations for Multiple Models** means working with a single database via multiple dbContext and Migrations, In **MVC5**!

Why?

Because i want to add new Entities to database from my Areas!..So each Area have their own `dbContext` and `Migrations` Files. i use Update-Database command in console package manager  and my database will update without any problem.

> As every body knows: You can update your database from each projects of your solution but if you set it as **StartUpProject** of solution.

and my challenge is about what i said in above *Blockquote* ! because in another step i want to update my database programmatically by this code:

```
      //ActionResult of my Area:  
     public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        migrator.Update(); //got Error in this line
        return View();
    }
```

i get

> network-related or instance-specific error

in specified line and i know why!..because my Area Project is not set as StartUpProject of my solution and it shouldn't be.

So how can i handle this situation in your view?

Answer (score 0):

I knew. i should give **ConnectionString** to my configuration instance, straightly like this:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {


        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(
                     "Server=.;Database=SegalFrameWork;Trusted_Connection=True;",
                     "System.Data.SqlClient");

        configuration.ContextKey = "BlogDbContext";
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        migrator.Update();
        return View();
    }
```

now there is no need to read connection string from web.config so it doesn't need any startup project to find it.